# SQL Server single query problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dynamic-queries

I have been trying to query some information but I can't seem to come up with the query. Below are the table information and my current queries.

Company table:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| CompanyID |  Address  | PostalCode |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| a-coy     | 31 street |     111111 |
| b-coy     | 32 street |     111222 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

Repair table:

```
+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------+
| SerialNo | CompanyID | PersonInCharge | RepairDate | RepairBy |
+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------+
|    15000 | a-coy     | John           | 01-May-17  | Jason    |
|    15001 | a-coy     | John           | 02-May-17  | Jack     |
+----------+-----------+----------------+------------+----------+
```

My aim is to draw query out the latest repair works entry which has only 1 results.

My current queries is as followed:

```
SELECT 
    c.companyid, c.address, r.repairdate, r.repairby
FROM 
    company c 
INNER JOIN 
    repair r ON c.companyID = r.companyID
WHERE 
    c.companyid = 'a-coy'
```

and I get the following results:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| CompanyID |  Address  | RepairDate | RepairBy |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| a-coy     | 31 street | 01-May-17  | Jason    |
| a-coy     | 31 street | 02-May-17  | Jack     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

But the results I wanted is only just the entry with the latest repair date and it would looks exactly like this :

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| CompanyID |  Address  | RepairDate | RepairBy |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| a-coy     | 31 street | 02-May-17  | Jack     |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1
c.companyid, 
c.address, 
r.repairdate,
r.repairby
FROM company c 
INNER JOIN repair r ON c.companyID=r.companyID
WHERE c.companyid = 'a-coy'
ORDER BY r.repairdate DESC
```

Comment: Yes. To make this run on production correctly make sure to add an index on repair date.

Comment: do not create an index when it is not needed. Try your query and if you have no performance problems than dont create index. Too many indexes can slow down inserts/updates statements

Comment: Thanks for the valuable help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the latest repair date for each company.

```
SELECT
    t.companyid,
    t.address,
    t.repairdate,
    t.repairby
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c.companyid,
        c.address,
        r.repairdate,
        r.repairby,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.companyid ORDER BY r.repairdate DESC) rn
    FROM company c
    INNER JOIN repair r
        ON c.companyID = r.companyID
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1 AND
      t.companyid = 'a-coy'
```

This would be a good choice if we wanted to obtain the latest repair record for more than one company.  The other answer given works well for a single company, but won't scale well for more than one company.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable help. Really appreciate it.